# Cordova / Phonegap, jQuery Mobile, Android, and sticky fixed footers

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

jQuery Mobile's (v1.1) fixed footers are suppose to stay on the bottom of the screen and float on top of the text and otherwise be visible at all times.  This works great in a browser, but when I bundle it up with Phonegap (now called Cordova) (v1.6) into an Android app the footer sticks wherever it first appears.  That is the footer scrolls with the text.

What's really weird is that when you tap the screen the header and footer get fixed to the top and the bottom of the page (this is jQuery Mobile built in functionality with fixed headers and footer) and when you tap it again the header and footer go back to floating.  But this time the footer stays at the bottom of the screen and doesn't scroll with the text, like it was suppose to from the start.

Any idea how to fix the footer?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="myfooter">
        <a href="#nextPage" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"  data-transition="slide">Continue</a>
    </div>
```

Here is an example of what I'm seeing.

[image: footer example]

Comment: tested your code and it works fine both on the simulator and my Samsung Galaxy with android 2.3.3, the markup seems to be correct. Could you provide more information like your testing device and/or the relevant css/js?

Comment: My simulator shows this bug in Android 2.1, did you get any further in diagnosing the problem @nroscoe?

Comment: they have completely reworked this for PhoneGap 1.8 I think, now it's at version 2.0 I'd expect it to work normally... shall we test and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed footer is working Jquery Mobile 1.2.  I did notice a lot of fix updates on the forum, so it probably has improved.  There is also an issue with the iOS slides up keyboard/inputs that move the footer to the middle of the page in error.

I'd definitely suggest upgrading to `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js` and going from there.  I had to do so and besides the buggy behaviour, the fixed footer works.

Comment: Note: the buggy behaviour you describe is still happening in 1.2, but when you click on the content of the page after the keyboard/inputs slide up.